# Can I ask how to simplify a piece of code?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'm a beginner yet, and simplifying my code is not easy for me yet, and I have actual working code, but it's too long, and I thought I would ask a question like:

"How could I simplify this XY code?"

But I don't know if people would actually be helpful with this or I would get downvotes only?

What do you think? Is such a question acceptable?

Comment: Is your question purely about layout / formatting / readability, or are you looking to make improvements that change functionality (e.g. performance, scope)?

Comment: Such a question would better be asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. So it will likely be closed as off topic.

Comment: This is off topic for Stack, so there is no way to post this and get a good reception. You may have your luck on code review (**disclaimer**: I am not a codereview regular. Please check their help center of validate If your question would be on topic there.)

Comment: I think you would get your question closed.  If you want to improve/refactor your working code/data/whatever, it MAY be on-topic at 'codereview' - check their rules/policy:)

Comment: Thank you for answers, I didn't know about that site so far :)

Comment: Check them out, but as the others have stated, do carefully look at their F.A.Q. since that site has stringent quality standards as well. It's not a dumping ground for invalid StackOverflow questions but rather has its own purpose and requirements. Good luck.